# 12 donuts split to 5 children

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose you buy 12 identical donuts and wish to give them to the 5 children you are babysitting. How many different ways
can you distribute the donuts if:
(a) there are no restrictions

My answer for this question is,

A) Combination with Repetition: (n+r-1,r) = (12+5-1,5) = (16,5)

B) But some people are getting different answers: (n+r-1,r) = (12+5-1,4)  = (16,4)
using the logic:
00|00|0000|000|0
there need to be 4 dividers to divide into 5 groups.

Please tell me which one is the right answer.

Comment: You have slightly misstated (B). Correctly stated it is the right answer: ${n+r-1\choose r-1}$. Take a row of 16 zeros and pick 4. Child A gets the number of 0s to the left of the first picked 0. Child B gets the number strictly between the first and second picked 0s and so on.

Comment: Your problem on (A) is that you have muddled $n$ and $r$. It is often expressed as $k$ things between $n$ people or $x_1+\dots+x_n=k$ and the answer is ${n+k-1\choose k}$ but here $n$ is playing the role of $r$ and $k$ is playing the role of $n$. Note that ${n+k-1\choose k}={n+k-1\choose n-1}$. So combination with repetition actually gives the same answer ${16\choose4}={16\choose12}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1, x_2,...,x_5$ be the kids, so we could model this problem as $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=12$ (because the donuts are identical).

This can be solved with a combination with repetition: ${5+12-1}\choose{12}$ = ${16}\choose{12}$.

**Edit:**

Another way of thinking this is suppose we have to place 12 balls in 5 containers. The balls are identical and the containers are not. Say those (°°°°°°°°°°°°) are the 12 balls.

1. First we take 2 balls and place it in a container. Now we have 12-2
   balls left. We are going to represent this as (°°|°°°°°°°°°°).
2. Again we take 4 balls and we place them in the second container. Now
   we have °°|°°°°|°°°°°°.
3. Again we take another 3 balls and we place them in the 3rd
   container: °°|°°°°|°°°|°°°.
4. Again we take another ball and place it in the 4th container:
   °°|°°°°|°°°|°|°°.
5. Now we have 2 balls left, which we put them in the 5th container.

In how many ways can we place the four | in the 16 spaces we have?

Comment: but my q is why is r 12 or 4, should it not be 5 because there are 5 children?

Comment: Tim Hortons sells 20 different kinds of donuts and always has at least a dozen of each type available. How many different
ways can someone buy a dozen donuts?
so in this case would this be (31,11) or (31,12)

Comment: Check my edit @SkandanVecham

Comment: That helps, as to what evers left foes into the last container thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The correct formula is $$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k-1}{n}.$$

---

To understand why this is, consider $n$ indistinguishable balls, and we need to put them into $k$ groups. Now, imagine for each group, we can separate them with dividers.

From here, we see we need $k-1$ dividers. Let's take a quick example:

**How many ways are there to place $5$ indistinguishable balls into $3$ boxes?**

*Solution.* We divide the groups by bars - for example, one possible way is $$**||***$$ As you can see, there are three groups:

- Group $1$: $2$ balls.
- Group $2$: $0$ balls.
- Group $3$: $3$ balls.

Another one would be like $$*|**|**$$ Experimenting with this a bit more, we see that we're just arranging $5$ balls and $2$ dividers, which can be done in $$\binom {5+2}2 = 21 \text{ ways}. \: \square$$

---

Now, for the general case:

We have to place $n$ balls in $k$ groups, which needs $k-1$ dividers. Then, using the example above, we conclude that there are $$\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k-1}{n}$$ ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are struggling with a formula.  Maybe it will help to change the numbers so you can easily tell what the result will be.  Assume there is $1$ kid rather than $5$.  Is the correct number of ways to distribute $12$ donuts to $1$ child $\binom{12}1$ or $\binom{12}0$?

Comment: (12,0), but for this q: Tim Hortons sells 20 different kinds of donuts and always has at least a dozen of each type available. How many different ways can someone buy a dozen donuts? Would the answer be (31, 20) or would it be (31,19).

Comment: @SkandanVecham Seems that the same stars and bars logic as in B. still applies.  I couldn't refute the logic of it for the original question or for this one.